# Function With No allowed Exceptions in Java

Tags: java, function, exception

In C++ I can declare a function which can not further throw exceptions as under

```
int myfunction (int param) throw(); // no exceptions allowed
```

Can I have such declaration in Java programming language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, any method can always throw an unchecked exception (`RuntimeException` and `Error`).

You only need to list checked exceptions (`Exception` subclasses that don't derive from `RuntimeException`) in the method declaration.

And an ugly side-note: while the compiler *does* check that no checked exception is thrown that is not declared, you *can* work around that with some ugly tricks (that's sometimes called a [sneaky throw](http://www.jayway.com/2010/01/29/sneaky-throw/), Project Lombok [supports it explicitly](http://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows.html)).

Comment: How about `myFunction() { try {....} catch ( Throwable t ) { /* ignore */ } }` :-)

Comment: You are right but I didn't got which ugly tricks are you talking about? Please elaborate

Comment: Technically, that doesn't throw an exception, but that doesn't mean that the method is *declared as throwing no exception". In C seeing the declaration in the question is enough to know that this function will never throw anything. In Java there is no equivalent declaration.

Comment: @Joachim: I know that, hence the smiley. Sumit and Mohit: Don't ever do this if you want to remain friends with me :-) It was only meant to bring a smile into your day.

Comment: @AndersRostgaardBystrup You are right but my sense of asking question was different. I wanted that if program compiled, I would be assured of no CheckedException is thrown like equivalent code in C++ in my question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, not in that sense. You can declare a function to not throw an exception (simply don't include the throws keyword), but you cannot prevent a function from throwing any exception at all. Imagine you will have division by zero in that function - the program's behaviour would be then undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way by which you can ensure that an exception will not at all be thrown to the previous layer. Simply put all your code in a try catch statement, so that even though any exception occurs in the method, it will always be catched.

But, remember it will only ensure that the exception will not propogate to the previous(calling) layer.It will surely not ensure that the exception will not at all occur in the method body